# Meaning of connect() in android programming

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I am not able to understand what is the use of `connect()` in the following code.

What is the difference in calling the `url.openConnection()` and `url.connect()` method?

```
URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
connection.connect(); // <-- Here
```

Comment: If you use windows or linux. put your cursor on the code in which you are confused. and then click ctrl+q. Even then if you don't understand, then google, even then if you don't understand, then ask the question that too specific to the part that you did not understand

Comment: What part of the Javadoc didn't you understand?

Comment: You need a `URLConnection` object in order to run `connect()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check their documentation at Android developer site's API documentation

By a small glimpse I could say the primary difference is that [openConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()) returns instance of URLConnection that is used to actually establish te connection, whereas the [connect](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect()) method returns nothing but opens the connection.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [URLConnection JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect()),

`connect()`

> Opens a communications link to the resource referenced by the URL, if such a connection has not already been established.
>   If the connect method is called when the connection has already been opened (indicated by the connected field having the value true), the call is ignored.

You can browse up on the [JavDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) or [Android Developer Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) in the future if you want to know more about a particular method or a class.